# Loading an attribue from element on external page

Tags: javascript, ajax, attributes, load, element

My page has a list of links that each loads new pages with ajax. These new pages contains a gallery of images and a main image.
   My objective is to get the source-url from the main image to show as a thumbnail on the corresponding link on the link page.

I have no idea how to go about this. If someone could point me in the right direction and maybe give me some code to follow I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an external page with jQuery.get.

```
$.get('my_external_page.html', function(data) {
  // data is the pages contents.
});
```

Then shove that into a div

```
$.get('my_external_page.html', function(data) {
  // data is the pages contents.
  var haystack = $('<div>').html(data);
  var needle = haystack.find('.image-we-want');

  var imageSrc = needle.attr('src');
});
```

That's a start. Of course it assumes you can use jquery, and the element you're searching for has a class or ID.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Probably not the smartest way to do it, but it works.

I have a page full of links (). I also have an empty div at the bottom of  called .
   The code loads an icon to these links. The links points to a new pages containing several images. The icons are  minified versions of the pages' standard images.

```
function iconPicHandler(){  
   var aTags = $('#linkpage a');
   for(var i = 0;  i < aTags.length; i++){
      $('#invisible').load('page3.html #standardImage',function(aLink){
         return function(){
            $('<img src="'+ $('#standardImage').attr("href") +'" />')
            .prependTo(aLink);
         }
      }
    ($(atags[i])));             
    }
    $('#invisible').hide();
}
```

So the first thing I do is get all the links in the linkpage. I put the rest of the code into a for-loop, so I can do the same for all the links.
   Then I load " #standardImage" from page3.html into "#invisible". #standardImage" is an empty div containing an url to a minified version of page3's standardImage. The url is held as the div's href attribute. 
   Then came the tricky part. I'm not sure what I did here. But as a callback function I made a function, that takes one argument, which is specified at the end($(atags[i])). This function then returns a new function! This enabled me to both have access to the atags(links) and the newly loaded $('#standardImage').
   Inside the function I extract the href from $('#standardImage') and use it as a src for an image prepended to the link.
   At the end, outside the for-loop, I hide $('#invisible').

As previously stated this is not a very smart way of doing this, but it gets the job done. Who knows, maybe it can help the next beginner walking by who just happen to have a similar problem.